# Is there any source code analysis tool for Elixir?

Tags: security, elixir, analysis

Is there any source code analysis tool that can detect **security** flaws in Elixir?

I know about Sobelow, but I am **not** using Phoenix framework.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly what you need, but we have a public database with Elixir Security Advisories for Elixir packages (unfortunately not so updated):

- https://github.com/dependabot/elixir-security-advisories

Currently we haven't a well known code analysis tool for pure Elixir, which would be listed on:

- https://github.com/mre/awesome-static-analysis
- https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Phoenix framework, sobelow won't help. Thus I would say used Clamxir,

https://github.com/ramortegui/clamxir

But purely based on your requirement and whether it does the necessary coverage.